# NativeLoader has not been initialized. To use standard native library loading

Tags: java, android, android-studio, news-ticker, whatsapp-stickers

getting an error while fetching a WhatsApp sticker pack in my app

```
NativeLoader has not been initialized. To use standard native library loading, call nativeloader.Init(new SystemDelegate()).
```

why this error show in logcat and sticker packs cannot fetch anyone solves this issue

Answer (score 6):

This is likely because the code uses the Fresco library, which has to be initialized as follows:

```
Fresco.initialize(this);
```

Where `this` shall be a `Context`. See the [Fresco docs](https://frescolib.org/docs/index.html) for more.